# how to write a becarre '(U+266E)?

Tags: characters

How can insert in the text special characters as "%" without begin a comment or insert a "becarre" (keyboard shortcut)?

Comment: Try `$\natural$`

Comment: Thank you, it's OK

Comment: It's also good to know that there are a lot of resources online to help you find how to insert symbols in LaTeX! For example, you can try [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), where you can draw a symbol to find it. There exists also huge lists of symbols, such as [this one](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `\%`. The special characters # $ % & _ { } can all be printed by `\#` `\$` etc.